# initialized without binding with angular

Tags: angularjs, binding

I need to initialized without binding.

I've tried the following. But I did not succeed

```
$scope.emptyRow = $scope.newsCategories[1];
$scope.newsCategories[1].Name = "yes";
$scope.emptyRow.Name = "test";
alert($scope.emptyRow.Name); // alert => test
alert($scope.newsCategories[1].Name);// alert => test
```

I need this :

```
$scope.emptyRow = $scope.newsCategories[1];
$scope.newsCategories[1].Name = "yes";
$scope.emptyRow.Name = "test";
alert($scope.emptyRow.Name); // alert => test
alert($scope.newsCategories[1].Name);// alert => yes
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with binding, but rather basic javascript.

The line: `$scope.emptyRow = $scope.newsCategories[1];`

is explicitly saying that you want `$scope.emptyRow` and `$scope.newsCategories[1]` to be pointing to the exact same object. Hence, when you change a child value of either (like `Name`), it will effect the other.

It looks like you want to be able to copy the object in question. For that you can use `angular.copy()`. An example use in your case would be:

```
$scope.emptyRow = angular.copy($scope.newsCategories[1]);
```

Read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) for more info.